# How to open a remote python program from terminal by ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh, python

I type `ssh -X name@blah.edu` and asks for a password,  I type it in and get logged in.

```
name@blah.edu:~$  program.py
```

then nothing happens, when it should actually pop up. Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Comment: @shi what does `echo $DISPLAY` print when you run it in your ssh session?

Comment: It displays     localhost:14.0

Comment: I added the information from your duplicate question which should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the SSH connection is not forwarding X11 commands over the connection.

If the machine you are using to connect is running Linux (or another OS with X) then simply pass the `-X` param when invoking SSH.

If you are connecting with Microsoft Windows, you will need a program that can translate X11 commands into Windows API commands. Try looking at [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: I typed      ssh -X name@blahblahblah.edu    got prompted for and typed in password,,, got logged in, then     typed "firefox" and nothing happened. Im using ubuntu.

Comment: Are there any errors reported?

Comment: no, just nothing pops up

Comment: @shi: Does the command terminate, or do you have to hit `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: I don't have to do anything, the terminal appears as normal, just like when I open a program locally, but when I'm in my remote account, the only difference is that the program doesn't pop up.

Comment: @shi: What I mean is: When you type `firefox` and press enter, does the command end immediately (you're back at the prompt), or does the nothing happen?

Comment: the window is the same, but without anything poping out,     so nothing happens    Like this _________nwuser@ubuntu:~$ gedit__________   then a COMPLETELY empty next line comes up

Comment: @shi: So if you type something on the next line (like `ls`) and press enter, nothing happens?

Comment: on the next line "nwuser@ubuntu:~$" does not show up, so when I type ls , ls  does not show, I am unable to type anything on  the next line

Comment: basically there is noting on the next line

Comment: @shi: That means that Firefox started without a problem. Could it be that it's just taking a while to show up?

Comment: I waited for a whole dayyyyyyyyyyyy, while doing stuff on my other computer, I don't know what's wrong, normlly it should just pop open, but it doesn't. uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @shi: What happens if you try running another app like `gedit`?

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to add/uncomment the following line from your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

The -X flag is useless without this.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to enable X forwarding in your SSH server's configuration file, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

`X11Forwarding yes`

If you don't have access to this file, I'm afraid you will have to ask your sysadmin to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as you do in your PC,
`ssh -X remotehost python remotepythonprogram.py`

To view the program code,
`ssh -X remotehost less remotepythonprogram.py`

Comment: nothing pops up, I try to open other programs from the remote computer that are not python, they don't open either.

Comment: @karthick87 given the `-X` flag in the connection string, I think we're talking about a graphical X-forwarded application, not a text-mode app.

Comment: yes something like fityk

Comment: why doesnt it pop up?

Comment: In addition, when I open a program from my local account using terminal, it works. FOr example, I type "firefox"...firefox pops up.   Then whe I ssh into my remote account, I type "firefox" nothing happens. What is the problem?

Comment: @shi firefox looks for already running firefox instances, and if it finds one, it tries to add another tab/window to that one instead of starting a new firefox browser. So you either need to kill your currently running firefox, or run `firefox -no-remote`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your DISPLAY variable is getting set somewhere. When I SSH into my machine from my phone (with X forwarding) and run the following:

```
oli@bert:~$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Though it's not a guarantee, X forwarding tends to use high display numbers.

If your `~/.bashrc` is set to override the display, you'll likely see something more like like `:0`.

You can either guess and over-override the `DISPLAY` variable to `localhost:10.0` after you connect:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

Of find where you're setting display in your local bash files.

---

I should add that it's possible to turn off X forwarding in the SSHd settings (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) so you might want to check that too.

Comment: My computer is originally a windows vista,then I used wubi to install ubuntu 10.04.1 . Normally at work when I type in the commands the program opens and pops up in a new window, now on my laptop ubuntu, I type in the exact same thing and nothing pops up.

Comment: @shi did you run `echo $DISPLAY` when connected via SSH? What did you see?

Answer (score 0):

Oliver's solution is the way to go if you want to forward X, but understand that this may be bandwidth-intensive.

An alternate solution is to use a command line editor like `vim` or `nano`. Personally, I would go with `vim`. It does have a steeper learning curve, but once you get past that, you will not want to go back to anything else =) You can start learning it by executing `vimtutor` for a tutorial on the basics.