# I can't open program from remote computer, why?

Tags: command-line, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open a remote python program from terminal by ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18047/how-to-open-a-remote-python-program-from-terminal-by-ssh)

When I open a program from my local account using terminal, it works. For example, I type "firefox"...firefox pops up. Then when I ssh into my remote account, I type "firefox" nothing happens. What is the problem?

`nwuser@ubuntu:~$ ssh -X name@blah.edu`

`name@blah.edu's password:`

I get logged in

`cynthia@fiber:~$ gedit`

nothing pops open after I hit ENTER